# Why function flow is not working normal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I am working on a nodeJS app i can not call functions in normal flow like I am defining.

```
console.log('1') 
require('../models/userModel')(UserCtrl);// inside this file i have console.log('2')
console.log('3')
```

Butt i am getting
1
3
2
instead of 1
2
3
 Here is my userModel code

```
var Waterline   = require('waterline'),
      config    = require('../config/db'),
       _        = require('lodash')
        orm     = new Waterline()

module.exports = function(refContObj){
    var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

      identity: 'user',
      connection: 'myLocalDBConn',

      attributes: {
        first_name: 'string',
        last_name: 'string'
      }
    });

    orm.loadCollection(User);
    orm.initialize(config,function(err, models){
        refContObj.models = models.collections;

        console.log('2') 
    });
}
```

Thanx

Comment: You would need to show a complete example we can try, including the place where you have the second console.log call.

Answer (score 2):

The initialize method on the orm object is asynchronous. That means that the control will be given to the code that follows your async method, the console.log('3') statement and when the initialize method is complete the callback that contains console.log('2') will be called.

```
require('../models/userModel')(UserCtrl, main);

function main() {
  console.log('3'); 
}
```

And the userModel code should be:

```
var Waterline   = require('waterline'),
      config    = require('../config/db'),
       _        = require('lodash')
        orm     = new Waterline()

module.exports = function(refContObj, cb){
    var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

      identity: 'user',
      connection: 'myLocalDBConn',

      attributes: {
        first_name: 'string',
        last_name: 'string'
      }
    });

    orm.loadCollection(User);
    orm.initialize(config,function(err, models){
        refContObj.models = models.collections;

        console.log('2');
        cb();

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bogdan Rotund your solution is working great. But is there any other solution to avoid this nested functions call ? function(arg,cb){} then function cb(arg, SecondCB){}... I just want to know about performance issue and complexity. Don't you think its getting complex ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the answer with callback it's correct.
And there are no way to do it simpler.
Optionally you can use promises instead of callbacks.
Here is useful comparison - 
http://spion.github.io/posts/why-i-am-switching-to-promises.html

Answer (score -1):

Please post your userModel.
Note: Using the `async` function there could cause this.